# Некоректная работа кнопки CSS

Tags: html, css, button

При увеличении колличества контента в кнопке, он не вмещается в заданную ширину, а вылазит за пределы самой кнопки. Необходимо, чтоб контент не изменял ширину кнопки, а рос в высоту при увеличении.

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/Kulko_P/pen/vYXeqQW?editors=1100)

```
<div class="header__nav-btn btn">
  <a class="header__btn-link btn-link" href="#">СвязатьсяСвязатьсяСвязаться</a>
</div>


.btn {
    width: 123px;
    border: 1px solid tomato;
}

.btn-link {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: можно добаить в стиль кнопки  word-break: break-word;

Comment: Хотя бы одно слово такой длины назовите ....

Answer (score 1):

В вашем примере несколько слов, которые не разделены пробелом. По факту получается как одно слово, ширина которого превышает ширину контейнера, поэтому и раздвигает его границы. Есть два варианта:

Вариант `overflow: hidden;` [Подробнее о свойстве](http://htmlbook.ru/css/overflow)

```css
.btn {
  width: 123px;
  border: 1px solid tomato;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.btn-link {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="header__nav-btn btn">
  <a class="header__btn-link btn-link" href="#">СвязатьсяСвязатьсяСвязатьсяСвязаться</a>
</div>
```

Вариант `word-break: break-word;` [Подробнее о свойстве](http://htmlbook.ru/css/word-break)

```css
.btn {
  width: 123px;
  border: 1px solid tomato;
  word-break: break-word;
}

.btn-link {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="header__nav-btn btn">
  <a class="header__btn-link btn-link" href="#">СвязатьсяСвязатьсяСвязатьсяСвязаться Связаться Связаться Связаться Связаться Связаться</a>
</div>
```